# Javascript generated table not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, html-table

Can anyone spot an obvious error? Why is this Javascript generated table (`showResults` function) not showing up in my html? This always happens when I have a lot of literal values to quote...I'd appreciate any other comments on my formatting (white-space) as well!

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //calculates sum of all values within an array
   function totalVotes(votes){  /
        var total=0;
        for (i=0;i<votes.length;i++){
        total = votes[i] + total;
        }
        return total;
    }
    //calculates a percentage, rounded to nearest integer
    function calcPercent(item, sum){    
        return Math.round((item/sum)*100);
    }
    //tests value of partyType parameter        
   function createBar(partyType, percent){   
        switch (partyType){
            case D:  barText="<td class='dem'></td>";
            break;
            case R:  barText="<td class='rep'></td>";
            break;
            case I:  barText="<td class='ind'></td>";
            break;
            case G:  barText="<td class='green'></td>";
            break;
            case L:  barText="<td class='lib'></td>";
            break;
        }
        for(i=1;i<=percent;i++){    
            document.write(barText);
        }
    }
    function showResults(race,name,party,votes){
        var totalV=function totalVotes(votes);

        document.write("<h2>" +race+ "</h2>");
        document.write("<table cellspacing='0'>");
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<th>Candidate</th>");
        document.write("<th class='num'> Votes</th>");
        document.write("<th class='num'>%</th>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        for (r=0;r<name.length;r++){
            document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<td>"+name[i]+ '(' +party[r]+ ")" +"</td>");
            document.write("<td class='num'>" +votes[r]+ "</td>");

            var percent=function calPercent(votes[r],totalV)
            document.write("<td class='num'>(" +percent[r]+ "%)</td>");
            createBar(party[r], percent);
            document.write("</tr>");
        }   
        document.write("</table>");
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure `var totalV=function totalVotes(votes);` is not valid Javascript. I think you mean `var totalV=totalVotes(votes);`.

Comment: Also this is invalid `for(i=1;i<=percent;i++)` as going back through your code here `document.write("<td class='num'>(" +percent[r]+ "%)</td>");`, I think you meant to write `for(i=1;i<percent.length;i++)`. One other point with your for-loops, it is better to use `var` when declaring the variable you iterate over so it is disposed after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many issues with your code:

1. Random slash after your opening brace to the `totalVotes` function
2. Declaring a variable without `var` with your for-loops (this wouldn't break your code but it isn't a good idea to do it)
3. As others stated, incorrect use of the switch statement (non-numeric characters need to be in quotes)
4. As Fabrizio Calderan stated, `barText` isn't set properly. It *will* work but it is very bad practice. Declare it first before the switch.
5. The for-loop in `createBar` will not work based on what you are passing to it. You pass an array as the value of `percent` in the for-loop inside `showResults` but then treat it like it is a number by comparing it to a number. You want `percent.length` in the for-loop instead.
6. Incorrect method of accessing a function. `var totalV=function totalVotes(votes);` is invalid and will not work. Alternatively use `var totalV=totalVotes(votes);` or if you don't want to use that, `var totalV=totalVotes.call(null, votes);` (Though you have no need to use the `.call` property in your code)
7. Another error inside your for-loop in the `showResults` function. `var percent=function calPercent(votes[r],totalV)` has both the issue as my #6 point with accessing a function incorrectly as well as that function does not actually exists due to a misspelling. Pretty sure you mean `var percent=calcPercent(votes[r],totalV)`.
8. I'm not a fan of the `document.write` method and haven't used it for a LONG time. I personally avoid it at all costs due to how it works / where it writes. Also as Fabrizio suggested, `innerHTML` is a much better option.

Overall, the code is clean and mostly works but I feel like you didn't even attempt to run the code with a debugger enabled. Both Firefox and Chrome have a decent native debugger and would spot these errors.

With that said though, I have fixed up your code with these issues. There are still a handful of other changes that could be done to make the code nicer/smaller/simpler but I think this will do for now.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //calculates sum of all values within an array
    function totalVotes(votes)
    {
        var total=0;
        for (var i=0; i < votes.length; i++){
            total = votes[i] + total;
        }
        return total;
    }
    //calculates a percentage, rounded to nearest integer
    function calcPercent(item, sum)
    {
        return Math.round((item/sum)*100);
    }
    //tests value of partyType parameter        
    function createBar(partyType, percent)
    {
        var barText = null;
        switch (partyType)
        {
            case 'D':  barText="<td class='dem'></td>";
            break;
            case 'R':  barText="<td class='rep'></td>";
            break;
            case 'I':  barText="<td class='ind'></td>";
            break;
            case 'G':  barText="<td class='green'></td>";
            break;
            case 'L':  barText="<td class='lib'></td>";
            break;
        }
        var result = "";
        for(var i=1;i<percent.length;i++)
        {
            result += barText;
        }
        return result;
    }
    function showResults(race,name,party,votes)
    {
        var totalV=totalVotes(votes);
        var result = "";

        result += "<h2>" +race+ "</h2>";
        result += "<table cellspacing='0'>";
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<th>Candidate</th>";
        result += "<th class='num'> Votes</th>";
        result += "<th class='num'>%</th>";
        result += "</tr>";

        var percent = 0;
        for (var r=0; r < name.length; r++){
            result += "<tr>";
            result += "<td>"+name[i]+ '(' +party[r]+ ")" +"</td>";
            result += "<td class='num'>" +votes[r]+ "</td>";

            percent = calcPercent(votes[r],totalV)
            result += "<td class='num'>(" +percent[r]+ "%)</td>";
            result += createBar(party[r], percent);
            result += "</tr>";
        }
        result += "</table>";

        document.body.innerHTML = result; // or document.write(result) if you prefer
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Turnerj! Your feedback was very helpful! You are right...I'm being counterproductive in not taking advantage of a debugger as I should. Thank you again, my teachers! I will learn!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to give quotes while comparing with strings, `Hence D is not same as "D".`

```
  switch (partyType){
            case "D":  barText="<td class='dem'></td>";
            break;
            case "R":  barText="<td class='rep'></td>";
            .......
```

Also as other have suggested, Remove function keyword while calling it.

```
var totalV = function totalVotes(votes);
```

should be

```
  var totalV = totalVotes(votes);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was being as formal as possible, I didn't realize it was incorrect!

Answer (score 1):

1) Use quotes on your case statements: `case "D"`, `case "R"`, ...

2) Use `innerHTML` method instead of document.write. Use it just once with a concatenated string and not inside a `for` loop.

3) `var totalV = function totalVotes(votes);` will raise an error: perhaps you may want to write `var totalV = totalVotes(votes);`

4) `barText` is not defined anywhere (declare it first with `var`)

---

If you're also insterested on generic suggestion, the entire switch can be avoided with an object lookup

```
function createBar(partyType, percent){   

    var cells     = "",
        cellclass = { 
          "D": "dem", "R": "rem", "I": "ind", "G": "green", "L": "lib" 
        }[partyType];


    for(var i = 1; i <= percent.length; i++){    
        cells += "<td class='" +  cellclass + "'></td>"
    }

    <yourtablerow>.innerHTML = cells; // <yourtablerow> is a reference to a table row.
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion with `createBar`, quite clever. One thing with his code though is that `percent` is an array which is passed in so it would need to be `percent.length` for your for-loop. :)

Comment: Yes ingenious suggestion ( which is utterly beyond me at this point-I've obviously just started out, haha). Mille grazie, Fabrizio!